# Scraping my CS teacher's website, then emailing me when the site is updated

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been working on creating an individual final project for my python CS class that checks my teacher's website on a daily basis and determines if he's changed any of the web pages on his website since the last time the program ran or not.

I would really love some suggestions for improving my code, especially since it works now! I have added some functionality to it, so that it runs via a cron job on a cloud server and sends out an email when a page changes!

```
import requests ## downloads the html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup ## parses the html
import filecmp ## compares files
import os, sys ## used for renaming files
import difflib ## used to see differences in link files
import smtplib ## used for sending email
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart ## used for areas of email such as subject, toaddr, fromaddr, etc.
from email.mime.text import MIMEText ## used for areas of email such as body, etc.

root_url = "https://sites.google.com"
index_url = root_url + "/site/csc110winter2015/home"

def get_site_links():
    '''
    Gets links from the website's list items' HTML elements
    '''
    response = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    links =  [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('li.topLevel a[href^=/site/csc110winter2015/]')]
    return links

def try_read_links_file():
    '''
    Tries to read the links.txt file; if links.txt is found, then rename links.txt to previous_links.txt
    '''
    try:
        os.rename("links.txt", "previous_links.txt")
        write_links_file()
    except (OSError, IOError):
        print("No links.txt file exists; creating one now.")
        write_links_file()
        try_read_links_file()

def write_links_file():
    '''
    Writes the links.txt file from the website's links 
    '''
    links = get_site_links()
    with open("links.txt", mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
        out_file.write('\n'.join(links))

def check_links():  
    '''
    Checks to see if links have changed since the last time the program was run.
    '''
    if filecmp.cmp("links.txt", "previous_links.txt") == True:
        ## If link data hasn't changed, do nothing
        pass
    else:
        ## Checks to see what changes, if any, have been made to the links, and outputs them to the console
        d = difflib.Differ()
        previous_links = open("previous_links.txt").readlines()
        links =  open("links.txt").readlines()
        diff = d.compare(previous_links, links)
        for difference in diff:
            if '- ' in difference:
                print(difference.strip() + "\nWas a removed page from the CSC110 website since the last time checked.\n")
            elif '+ ' in difference:
                print(difference.strip() + "\nWas an added page to the CSC110 website since the last time checked.\n")

def try_read_pages_files():
    '''
    Tries to read the pages .txt files; if pages .txt are found, then rename the pages .txt files to previous_ pages .txt
    '''
    with open("links.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as pages:
        for page in pages:
            try:
                os.rename(page.replace("/",".") + ".txt", "previous_" + page.replace("/",".") + ".txt")
            except (OSError, IOError):
                print("No pages .txt file exists; creating them now.")
                write_pages_files()
                try_read_pages_files()
                ## Note that the call to write_pages_files() is outside the loop
        write_pages_files()

def write_pages_files():
    '''
    Writes the various page files from the website's links 
    '''
    with open("links.txt") as links:
        for page in links:
            site_page = requests.get(root_url + page.strip())
            soup = BeautifulSoup(site_page.text)
            souped_up =  soup.find_all('div', class_= "sites-attachments-row")
            with open(page.replace("/",".") + ".txt", mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as out_file:
                out_file.write(str(souped_up))

def check_pages():
    '''
    Checks to see if pages have changed since the last time the program was run.
    '''
    with open("links.txt") as links:
        changed_pages = []
        for page in links:
            page = page.replace("/",".")
            if filecmp.cmp("previous_" + page + ".txt", page + ".txt") == True:
                ## If page data hasn't changed, do nothing
                pass
            else:
                ## If page data has changed, then write the changed page data to a list
                if page == '.site.csc110winter2015.system.app.pages.sitemap.hierarchy':
                    pass
                else:
                    changed_pages.append(root_url + page.replace(".","/").strip())
        return changed_pages

def send_mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    ## Say ehlo to my lil' friend!
    server.ehlo()
    ## Start Transport Layer Security for Gmail
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    if check_pages():
        ## Setting up the email
        server.login("Sending Email", "Password")
        fromaddr = "Sending Email"
        toaddr = "Receiving Email"
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = fromaddr
        msg['To'] = toaddr
        msg['Subject'] = "Incoming CSC110 website changes!"
        # Can't return list and concatenate string; implemented here for check_pages()
        changed_pages =  "The following page(s) have been updated:\n\n" + str(check_pages())
        msg.attach(MIMEText(changed_pages, 'plain'))
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

def main():
    try_read_links_file()
    try_read_pages_files()
    check_links()
    check_pages()
    send_mail()
main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Bugs

The e-mail lists the pages whose contents have changed, but not the pages that were added or removed.  Additions and deletions are merely printed to `sys.stdout`.

The files where the page contents are saved have filenames of the form `previous_.site.csc110winter2015.somethingsomething␤.txt`.  The newline character preceding `.txt` is weird.

If the links are merely reordered, you'll see it reported as a removal and addition.

If `try_read_links_file()` is unable to create `links.txt` (due to directory permissions, for example), it will recurse infinitely.

### Inefficiencies

You call `check_pages()` up to three times:

- Once in `main()` for no apparent reason
- Once in `send_mail()` in an apparent attempt to check whether any changes were detected.  Bizarrely, this check is done *after* the SMTP handshake — why bother connecting to the SMTP server at all if you have nothing to send?
- If you do decide to send mail, then you call `check_pages()` once more to incorporate the list of modified pages in the message body.

### General critique

The technique you have employed is **very file-centric**.  The five functions that you call from `main()` communicate with each other not by passing parameters and returning values, nor via global variables, but through the filesystem!  This style of programming drastically complicates the code.  Every function ends up being concerned with reading files, stripping newlines (if you remember to do so), mangling paths, and saving the results.

`try_read_pages_files()` is misleadingly named, as it actually also writes the files.  Similarly, `try_read_links_file()` has side-effects that I wouldn't expect.

If you just want to detect whether content has changed, you need not save the entire website's contents.  Storing a cryptographic checksum of each page will suffice.  With that insight, you can **summarize the entire website in a single file**, one line per page.

It would be nicer to pass the whole initial URL to the program, rather than breaking it up into a `root_url` and an `index_url`.  Also, appending the `href` values to the `root_url` makes a nasty assumption that all of the `href`s are absolute URLs.  Use `urllib.parse.urljoin()` to resolve URLs instead.

In `send_mail()`, first compose the message, then send it.  Avoid interleaving the two operations.  You don't need multi-part MIME if all you are sending is a plain-text message.

In the suggested solution below, look at `main()` to see how functions should interact with each other.

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from hashlib import sha256
from smtplib import SMTP
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from urllib.request import urlopen

def summarize_site(index_url):
    '''
    Return a dict that maps the URL to the SHA-256 sum of its page contents
    for each link in the index_url.
    '''
    summary = {}
    with urlopen(index_url) as index_req:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(index_req.read())
        links = [urljoin(index_url, a.attrs.get('href'))
                 for a in soup.select('li.topLevel a[href^=/site/csc110winter2015/]')]
        for page in links:
            # Ignore the sitemap page
            if page == '/site/csc110winter2015/system/app/pages/sitemap/hierarchy':
                continue    
            with urlopen(page) as page_req:
                fingerprint = sha256()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page_req.read())
                for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='sites-attachments-row'):
                    fingerprint.update(div.encode())
                summary[page] = fingerprint.digest()
    return summary

def save_site_summary(filename, summary):
    with open(filename, 'wt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for path, fingerprint in summary.items():
            f.write("{} {}\n".format(b64encode(fingerprint).decode(), path))

def load_site_summary(filename):
    summary = {}
    with open(filename, 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            fingerprint, path = line.rstrip().split(' ', 1)
            summary[path] = b64decode(fingerprint)
    return summary

def diff(old, new):
    return {
        'added': new.keys() - old.keys(),
        'removed': old.keys() - new.keys(),
        'modified': [page for page in set(new.keys()).intersection(old.keys())
                     if old[page] != new[page]],
    }

def describe_diff(diff):
    desc = []
    for change in ('added', 'removed', 'modified'):
        if not diff[change]:
            continue
        desc.append('The following page(s) have been {}:\n{}'.format(
            change,
            '\n'.join(' ' + path for path in sorted(diff[change]))
        ))
    return '\n\n'.join(desc)

def send_mail(body):
    ## Compose the email
    fromaddr = "Sending Email"
    toaddr = "Receiving Email"
    msg = MIMEText(body, 'plain')
    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr
    msg['Subject'] = "Incoming CSC110 website changes!"

    ## Send it
    server = SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("Sending Email", "Password")
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

def main(index_url, filename):
    summary = summarize_site(index_url)
    try:
        prev_summary = load_site_summary(filename)    
        if prev_summary:
            diff_description = describe_diff(diff(prev_summary, summary))
            if diff_description:
                print(diff_description)
                send_mail(diff_description)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    save_site_summary(filename, summary)

main(index_url='https://sites.google.com/site/csc110winter2015/home',
     filename='site.txt')
```

Comment: Your code is beautiful! Thank you for not only suggesting improvements that I can make so that I can write a more efficient scraper in the future, but also for writing out the code so that I can actually see your suggestions implemented.